# How to conditionally restrict access to class fields using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to restrict the access to certain properties based on a given input when instantiating a class in TypeScript.

For example, if I give my class a context of `birds`, I would like to get a warning when I try to access `myClass.dog`.

```
type Context = 'birds' | 'mammals'

class MyClass {
    readonly chicken: string | never
    readonly duck: string | never
    readonly dog: string | never
    readonly cat: string | never

    constructor(context: Context) {
        if (context === 'birds') {
            this.chicken = 'chicken'
            this.duck = 'duck'
        }
        if (context === 'mammals') {
            this.dog = 'dog'
            this.cat = 'cat'
        }
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass('birds')

const dog = myClass.dog // I would like to get a warning that dog is of type never. (not a string)
```

I am not sure how to modify the type definitions to achieve that. Should I use infer?

Comment: Why is this one class at all? What's the context?

Comment: You should just make a function that returns DIFFERENT classes or subclasses instead of trying to cram everything into one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's not `never` if you don't initialize it, it's `undefined`.  `string | never` is just `string`.  Could you [edit] to switch from `never` to `undefined`?  That will not fix your issue (which really should be fixed via some kind of class hierarchy or discriminated union) but it will at least not be as distracting.

Answer (score -3):

```
type Context = 'birds' | 'mammals'

class MyClass {
    readonly chicken: string | never
    readonly duck: string | never
    readonly dog: string | never
    readonly cat: string | never

    constructor(context: Context) {
        if (context === 'birds') {
            this.chicken = 'chicken'
            this.duck = 'duck'
        }
        if (context === 'mammals') {
            this.dog = 'dog'
            this.cat = 'cat'
        }
    }
}

const myClass = new MyClass('birds')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation and/or thoughts.